# Convert MSG files to EML files

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, ad-free

I need to convert Outlook Emails in MSG file format into the EML file format.

Other requirements:

- does not send the data to "the cloud" or some online service for conversion
- does not have unknown limitations
- does not need admin privileges
- works on Windows 10
- is gratis
- allows commercial use (use in a company)
- does not contain ads or nasty "pro version" reminders (a gentle donation button is acceptable)

Optional:

- ideally does not need Outlook to be installed

I tried:

- [OutlookConvertMSG2EML](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookConvertMSG2EML), which has unknown limitations. It just says "download the free limited version".
- [Zamzar](https://www.zamzar.com/de/convert/msg-to-eml/) is an online service, but I really can't upload emails to the Internet. This would violate GDPR, NDAs and whatever.
- [InMedia Email Converter](https://www.in-mediakg.com/software/email-converter/e-mail-converter.shtml) needs Outlook installed and needs admin rights (what?, why?)
- [CoolUtils](https://www.coolutils.com/de/online/MSG-to-EML) is an online converter
- [msg2eml](https://www.jitbit.com/msg2eml/) is an online utility again
- [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/) fails with "Error: IConverterSession not found."
- [ReliefJet Essentials](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookConvertMSG2PDF?src=fw) is not gratis
- [MSGconvert](https://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/) is for Linux
- [PstViewer](https://www.encryptomatic.com/pstviewer/) is not gratis
- [Msg-Viewer](https://www.arysontechnologies.com/msg-viewer/) is not gratis
- [FreeViewer](https://www.freeviewer.org/msg/) despite its name is neither free nor gratis
- [MailsDaddy Free MSG Viewer](https://www.mailsdaddy.com/free-msg-viewer/) allows commercial use, but needs the Pro upgrade to convert to EML or save to any other format.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for tools, these tools will help you

Tools

1. Gaintools MSG to EML converter
2. Softaken MSG to EML Converter
3. Mailvita MSG to EML for MAC

Comment: Thank you. Hyperlinks to the products would be nice. Maybe you can [edit] them in.